# No me retorna un valor de una promesa que tiene una promesa

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, promesas

no he podido hacer que me devuelva un valor, siempre me sale undefine. Este es el codigo:

```
 signUp = async () => {

        this.checkSignUp(this.state.userName, this.state.userMail)
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
        })
    
}
checkSignUp = async (userName, userMail) => {
    let checkResult

    this.props.getBripcNotesUsers()
    .then(result => {
        const users = result

        const userNameFound = users.filter(user => user.data().profile.name == userName).length > 0
        const userMailFound = users.filter(user => user.data().profile.mail == userMail).length > 0

        if(userNameFound){
            console.log("This user name is already in use")

            checkResult = 1
        }else if(userMailFound){                
            console.log("This user mail is already in use")
            
            checkResult = 2
        }else{
            checkResult = true
        }

        return checkResult
    })
}
```

he probado y si me funciona cuando retorno un valor fuera de la promesa **getBripcNotesUsers()**, pero no dentro que es lo que necesito.

He probado en vez de usar una variable y modificarlo segun la condicion, retornarlo en cada condicion.:

```
   this.props.getBripcNotesUsers()
    .then(result => {
        const users = result

        const userNameFound = users.filter(user => user.data().profile.name == userName).length > 0
        const userMailFound = users.filter(user => user.data().profile.mail == userMail).length > 0

        if(userNameFound){
            console.log("This user name is already in use")

            return 1
        }else if(userMailFound){                
            console.log("This user mail is already in use")
            
            return 2
        }else{
            return true
        }
    })
```

Comment: No uses `then`,  usa `await`.

Comment: donde, acabo de probar en la funcion signUp y me sale igual

Comment: `let result = await this.props.getBripcNotesUsers();`. Luego haces todo lo que necesitas con `result` y devuelves lo que necesites usar en `checkSignup`

Comment: sisi, muchas gracias me funcionó

Comment: Pongan la respuesta como respuesta carai :)

Comment: como pongo que esta respondida

Comment: tambien con tu código actual, creo que solo bastaría poner el return aqui:
`return this.props.getBripcNotesUsers().then(.....)`

Comment: ya esta la respuesta como respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La clave es que las funciones regresen una promesa para poder encadenarlas, por ejemplo, checkSignUp debe regresar una promesa aun cuando esta consume una promesa como tal, asimismo, dentro del then de la promesa se regresa una promesa para poder hacer el encadenamiento.

Igual no es necesario marcar las funciones como asíncronas si no se utiliza el await dentro de ellas, se siguen ejecutando de forma sincrona.

```js
 const signUp = async () => {
        /// Este codigo se debe estar implementando en otra parte
        /// agrego para ejecutar la función en este contexto
        this.state = { userName: 'username', userMail: 'usermail' }
        /// Comentando this para poder ejecutar función en este contexto.
        /*this.*/checkSignUp(this.state.userName, this.state.userMail)
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
        })
        
}

const checkSignUp = async (userName, userMail) => {
    let checkResult

    /// Como no se proporciona implementación,
    /// simulo escenario donde getBripcNotesUsers()
    /// devuelve una colección vacía
    /// Regresar la ejecución de la promesa para el encadenamiento
    // return this.props.getBripcNotesUsers()
    return new Promise((res, rej) => res([]))
    .then(result => {
        const users = result

        /// Como no se tiene los detalles de implementacion,
        /// simulo escenario donde el usuario no se encontró
        const userNameFound = false //users.filter(user => user.data().profile.name == userName).length > 0
        const userMailFound = false //users.filter(user => user.data().profile.mail == userMail).length > 0

        if(userNameFound){
            console.log("This user name is already in use")

            checkResult = 1
        }else if(userMailFound){                
            console.log("This user mail is already in use")
            
            checkResult = 2
        }else{
            checkResult = true
        }

        // Debe regresar una promesa para poder ser consumido con .then / await
        return new Promise((res, rej) => res(checkResult))
    })
}

signUp();
```

Por cierto, porque combinar una función que regresa números y valores lógicos, sugiero solo regresar un tipo de datos para una validación más adecuada/limpia.

Comment: si, tienes razon, lo tendre en cuenta la proxima vez si esque no lo cambio